# Does any molecule other than DNA have a double-helical structure?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, structural-biology, 3d-structure, dna-helix

DNA is known to have a double-helical structure. Do any other molecules have this structure?

Comment: Probably also interesting to ask: was their molecular structure known before that of DNA?

Comment: Double Stranded RNA Actin Filament Collagen protein Starch is kind of similar too

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A few examples:

---

### [Starch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starch)

A polymer of glucose that can form a double helix and functions primarily as energy storage in plants.

[image]

[[image source](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed077p988)]

---

### [f-Actin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actin)

Filamentous actin forms a helical structure with two strands of polymerized g-actin. This is a structural component of the [cytoskeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoskeleton).

[image]

[[image source](http://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/19)]

---

### [Coiled Coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coiled_coil)

Protein motif with a helical structure formed by two (or more) [α-helices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix). Coiled coils are found in a diverse range of proteins from structural proteins like [keratin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratin) to transcription factors like [c-Fos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-Fos).

[image]

[[image source](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleHtml/2015/MB/c5mb00119f)]

---

### [Gramicidin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramicidin)

A peptide-based antibiotic that has been shown to form membrane spanning double helices.

[image]

[[image source](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1bdw)]

Answer (score 17):

Yes, [double-stranded RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA#Double-stranded_RNA) as found in [some viruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-stranded_RNA_viruses).

Comment: Do you know of any other such molecule? RNA is very similar to DNA, but is there a molecule that is very different from DNA and yet still has a double helix structure?

Comment: Yes, I thought you'd be only half satisfied with this answer. I do not know of any other molecules (but I am not a good chemist) but the answer may depend upon how different the structure of a molecule can be until you start considering its structure to really be different.

Answer (score 12):

The structural protein [collagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen) consists of a *triple* helix of polypeptides. Whether this answers the question is arguable—you could say that the triple helix contains double helices. In any case, depending on what prompted your question, I thought it might be an interesting structure to consider.

[image: Collagen-like peptide triple helix consisting of three peptide molecules (orange, blue, purple)]